# how to tell logrotate to compress and keep only X rotations from an externally rotated log files?

Tags: logging, logrotate

I have a java application which uses log4j and is setup to write to server.log and rotate the current log into server.log.YYYY-MM-DD on a daily basis. I would like to setup logrotate, such that it will compress all not-compressed logs matching server.log.YYYY-MM-DD and only keep 5 copies. I have been toying with this config, which doesn't seem to do it!

```
/var/log/srv/server.log.* {
  daily
  rotate 0
  compress
  nodelaycompress
  nocopy
  nocopytruncate
  nocreate
  missingok  
  maxage 5
}
```

Comment: Maybe rotate 5?

Comment: Wouldn't `rotate 5` rotate my already rotated files? I want these to be superseded by compressed copies.

Comment: Test it.  I think because daily is set, you can run it lots of times but still keep 5 days worth.

Comment: Tried it, but does not solve my problem, sadly.

Comment: If you just want to rotate non compressed logs that log4j has already rotated and delete old logs then a shell script would do the job.